# Behaviour of $\|f\|_{\lambda,[0,T]}$ as $T\to0$.

Tags: real-analysis, holder-spaces

Let $f:[0,T]\to\Bbb R$ be $\alpha$-Holder continuous function, for some $0<\alpha\le1$.
Then
$$
\|f\|_{\lambda,[0,T]}:=\sup_{0\le s<t\le T}\frac{|f(t)-f(s)|}{|t-s|^{\alpha}}<+\infty.
$$

Now it's clear that $\|f\|_{\lambda,[0,T]}\to0$ as $T\to0$.

Is it known *how* it goes to zero? For example, does exists some function of $\alpha$, say $\eta(\alpha)$ such that
$$
\lim_{T\to0}\frac{\|f\|_{\lambda,[0,T]}}{T^{\eta(\alpha)}}=1?
$$

**EDIT:** above I wrongly wrote "now it's clear that...". This is not true as pointed out by Davide Giraudo and Fred.

However I am interested in the same question *supposing* that: that is, IF $\|f\|_{\lambda,[0,T]}\to0$ as $T\to0$, is it known *how* it goes to zero?

Comment: "Now it's clear that $\|f\|_{\lambda,[0,T]}\to0$ as $T\to0$." Is it so clear? What if $f(t)=t^\alpha$?

Comment: I though about this only after having posted. I'm melting, sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x)=x$ and $ \alpha=1$. Then $\|f\|_{\lambda,[0,T]}=1$ for all $T>0$ !

Comment: I took off the accepted answer: it is not disrespect to you, I did this simply because I've expanded my answer.